# Find the inverse cdf of Y: find $F ^{−1}_ Y (y)$.

Tags: probability, statistics

> $$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
> \frac{3}{4} & : 0 ≤ y ≤ 1 − x^2, −1 ≤ x ≤ 1 \\ 0 & : \textsf{elsewise}\end{cases}$$
>
> find $ {F}_Y^{\raise{.5ex}{−1}}(y)$.

So far **I** have that $f(y) = \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{1-y}$ but I don't know how to get the inverse cdf from that

Answer (score 4):

Integrating your expression for $f(y)$, we find that $F_Y(y)=1-(1-y)^{3/2}$ for $0\le y\le 1$, $0$ for $y\lt 0$, and $1$ for $y\gt 1$. To find the inverse function, set $w=1-(1-y)^{3/2}$ and solve for $y$. We get $y=1-(1-w)^{2/3}$.

But since they want us to use the variable $y$, we have $F_Y^{-1}(y)=1-(1-y)^{2/3}$, when $0\le y\le 1$.

Comment: Your CDF should be nondecreasing...

Comment: @Ian: Thanks, I fixed the "$0$ elsewhere."